# Синхронизация вставки в Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis

Имеется `N: N > 1` клиентов расположенных на разных серверах. В таком сценарии возможна ситуация когда множество клиентов пытаются записать данные в `Redis` из-за их истекшего `TTL`, а это влечет за собой дополнительные запросы к `DB`. Количество запросов к `DB` При `N: N = 8` равно 8. Требуется минимизировать количество обращений к `DB`.

---

Схема: `User -> API -> DB || Redis -> User`.

---

Один из вариантов - использование встроенного в `Redis` механизма блокировок. Пример ниже иллюстрирует добавление записи с учетом блокировки ключа. Ожидается, что при указанных условиях будет выполнен только один запрос к `DB`.

```
public override async Task<T> SetItemAsync<T>(string k, Func<Task<T>> action, TimeSpan TTL)
{
    // Вероятно клиент, что один
    // из клиент завершил запись.
    T v = await GetFromCache<T>(k);

    // Если данные в Redis есть, 
    // возвращаем, а иначе 
    // пытаемся добавить.
    if (!IsDefault(v))
        return v;

    // Время на которое блокируется ключ.
    // Может зависить от типа данных.
    // Сделать конфигурируемым.
    TimeSpan _lockTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

    // Время окончания блокировки.
    DateTime _lockTimeoutEnd = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_lockTimeout.TotalSeconds);

    // Пытаемся получить блокировку
    // с учетом таймаута.
    while (DateTime.Now < _lockTimeoutEnd)
    {
        // _lockToken - Environment.MachineName.
        if (_db.LockTake(k, _lockToken, _lockTimeout))
        {
            try
            {
                // Получаем данные из DB. Возможны случаи
                // когда выполнения данного участка кода
                // не уложится в таймаут блокировки.
                v = await action();

                // Записываем данные в Redis.
                await SetToCache(k, v, TTL);

                // Публикуем сообщение в соответствующий канал, чтобы
                // остальные клиенты перезапросили из Redis данные с
                // заданным ключем и перезаписали локальный кеш. Это
                // для случая когда будет использоваться Redis + LocalMemory.
                await _db.PublishAsync(PubSubMessageType.CACHE_RESETED.ToString(), k);
            }
            finally
            {
                _db.LockRelease(k, _lockToken);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(50);

            // Вероятно клиент, что один
            // из клиент завершил запись.
            v = await GetFromCache<T>(k);

            if (!IsDefault(v))
                return v;
        }
    }

    return default;
}
```

1. Корректен ли `Retry` механизм? Если получить блокировку не получится, вызывающий код не получит данных, правильно ли это? Подразумевается, что он сам решит, что в таком случае делать.
2. Из-за установленного таймаута вечной блокировки быть не может, например из-за неудачно завершившегося потока, который ранее получил блокировку. Так или иначе один из клиентов или потоков в рамках того же клиента установит значение.
3. В случае когда получить блокировку не получилось, попыток снять ее не производится. Подразумевается, что другой клиент или поток в рамках того же клиента получит блокировку в результате ее таймаута.
4. Является ли overhead'ом попытки считать информацию в рамках описанного процесса?
5. Подразумевается, что доступ к методу `SetItemAsync` синхронизирован в рамках клиента.

---

*П.3. Если выставлять таймаут блокировки с учетом данных, которые будут извлекаться из `DB`, может возникнуть ситуация когда задан долгий таймаут, тогда следует снять блокировку принудительно. Как тут грамотно поступить?*

---

Вопросов оставленно больше одного, но тем не менее. Правильна ли реализация с учетом поставленной цели? Ответы на вопросы из пунктов 1-5 тоже привествуются. Может что-то не учтено или в корне неправильно.

---

- Данные изменяются довольно часто, т.е могут считатся неактуальными через 60 секунд или раньше.
- Обращения за данными происходят постоянно.

---

Дополнительная информация:

`Redis` - 4.0.11. 3 VM. Clustered | `.NET Client` - [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас у вас данные выбрасываются исключительно по TTL. Значит, вас устраивает неактуальность данных в кэше течении TTL секунд. Т.е. реальные ограничения у вас:

- Отставание кэша от данных в базе допустимо, данные в кэше должны отставать от реальных данных в базе не больше чем на N секунд (N = ваш текущий TTL)
- Обращения в кэш идут постоянно, гораздо чаще чем раз в N секунд
- Выборка тяжелая, одновременные запросы с нескольких серверов убивают базу.

Этим ограничениям полностью соответствует Upfront population:

- Делаете один отдельный сервис, который регулярно, чаще, чем раз в N секунд читает данные из базы, и кладет их в кэш.
- Все сервера просто читают из кэша.

При необходимости - триггерите заселение кэша не по таймеру, а по событиям изменения данных - и получаете минимальное отставание кэша от реальных данных, сравнимое с временем выполнения прямой выборки.

Comment: `Значит, вас устраивает неактуальность данных в кэше течении TTL секунд` Не очень понял откуда это следует. Данные, которые попадают в кэш формируются на основе постоянно изменяющегося потока данных. Доходит до того, что какие-то данные не живут дольше 4 секунд, какие-то дольше 60 секунд. В соответствии с обрабатываемыми данные устанавливается `TTL`, чтобы пользователь не увидел их. Т.е `TTL` - время актуальности данных.

Comment: @UserName сейчас вы для инвалидации кэша используете TTL. Это означает, что в данные, прочитанные из кэша, могут отставать от данных в базе на TTL секунд. И это вас вроде как устраивает. Пример - у вас есть что-то с TTL = 15 секунд. Если это что-то поменяется через секунду после заполнения кэша - то в кэше 14 секунд будут лежать неактуальные данные (и все клиенты будут получать эти неактуальные данные следующие 14 секунд). Раз это не вызывает проблем, и вы не пытаетесь это бороть в первую очередь - значит вас это устраивает.

Comment: Представленое решение разве не решает проблему? Смена подхода означает, что решение выбрано не верно?

Comment: Есть данные для который параметры их получения статичны, а с динамическими что делать?

Comment: @UserName и решение из вопроса и решение из ответа ничего не делают с актуальностью данных. Она как могла отставать на N/TTL секунд, так и продложит отставать. Решение из ответа можно довести до минимального отставания + снизить нагрузку за счет пересчета по событиям / гранулярного пересчета (только того, что поменялось, а не всего подряд). Это стандартный паттерн materialized view, поищите реализации под redis.